# java spring mvc many to many

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, many-to-many

I'm trying to make a many-to-many example app with spring mvc and hibernate.

I have 2 classes, book and author. I've mapped these 2 class created all relations, but the problem is I can't add values to my join table.

Where's the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE author
(
  author_id serial NOT NULL,
  author_name character(100),
  CONSTRAINT author_pkey PRIMARY KEY (author_id)
)
CREATE TABLE book
(
  book_id serial NOT NULL,
  book_name character(50) NOT NULL,
  price integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT book_pkey PRIMARY KEY (book_id)
)
CREATE TABLE book_author
(
  book_id integer NOT NULL,
  author_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT book_author_pkey PRIMARY KEY (book_id, author_id),
  CONSTRAINT book_author_author_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
      REFERENCES author (author_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT book_author_book_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
      REFERENCES book (book_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

and my java files

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int book_id;

    @Column
    private String book_name;

    @Column
    private int price;  

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_author", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") }
            )
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>();
    //geters and setters
}
```

Author.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="author_id")
    private int author_id;  

    @Column
    private String author_name; 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
//getters and setters
}
```

BookDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class BookDAOImpl implements BookDAO{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(book); 
    }
}
```

BookServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService{

    @Autowired
    private BookDAO bookDAO;

    @Override
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        bookDAO.addBook(book);
    }
}
```

BookController.java

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("authors")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorService authorService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newBook", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newBook(ModelAndView model) {
        Book book = new Book();
        model.addObject("book", book);
        model.setViewName("bookForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveBook(@ModelAttribute Book book,BindingResult result) 
    {
        if (book.getBook_id() == 0) { 
            // if employee id is 0 then creating the
            // employee other updating the employee
            bookService.addBook(book);
        } else {
            bookService.updateBook(book);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/newBook");
    }

    @ModelAttribute("authors")
    public List<Author> getAuthors(){
        return authorService.getAuthors();
    }
}
```

and finally here is bookForm.jsp file

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>New/Edit Book</h1>
        <form:form action="saveBook" method="post" modelAttribute="book">
        <table>
            <form:input type="hidden" path="book_id"/>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="book_name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price:</td>
                <td><form:input path="price" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Author:</td>
                <td><form:select path="authors" items="${authors}" itemValue="author_id" itemLabel="author_name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
```

After the page opens, I enter some book name and price and choose an author and click the Save button. It saves book but not saves the join table book_author.

[As you can see I can send author_id from ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymfSx.png)png

[And I can insert book object to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBaui.png)

Comment: do you get any exception when you save.

Comment: no there is no exception just see the hibernate log for inserting the book object but there is no insertion about book_author object

Comment: suppose you take a look at this [example](http://websystique.com/springmvc/springmvc-hibernate-many-to-many-example-annotation-using-join-table/) and try to find what is missing your project.

Comment: oo yes i used exactly the same example :) i just didnt use the enum for inverse join table but it didn't works now

Comment: pls print book.getAuthors() to console. i think list authors is emty.

Comment: Yes when I debug I saw that I can't get author object from form. But when I debug on browser I can see the selected author object id